# Node js : How can I integrate authorization and authentication to my node application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node application, I have an `admin` that can make all requests and the normal user that has the right to make only certain requests.

example:

admin cans make:

post on `/root, /user, /tools`

simple users can make:

post on `/users, /tools`

If a simple user tries to make a request on `/root`, he just receives and error message.

How can I handle this is node js? which package, if possible few examples.

thank

Comment: These kinds of questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, I know many people use [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) user authentication and authorization.

Comment: @MikeC is it not a coding question?  Can you please explain a bit why it is off-topic?

Comment: Because you're asking for a package which will accomplish this for you. Even if you removed that line, authorization/authentication is a hard problem and is too broad of a question to answer in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general approach should be define a custom middleware to verify the authentication

```
function VerifyUser(req, res, next){
 if(user.isAuthenticated){
   return next(); //call the next middleware
 }
 next(err); //call the error middleware 

}
```

error handler

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if(!err) return next(); 
    res.status(500).json(new Error('error happened'));
});
```

and then for each route that needs authentication bind the `VerifyUser` middleware **before** the router middleware.
Since in express the middleware order is relevant, `VerifyUser` will be called at first, and if the branch reach the `next()` call your routing function will be triggered.

**Authenticated routes:**

```
router.get('/root', VerifyUser, function(req, res){
 //if you reach this point means the user has been granted the access

})
```

**Non-authenticated routes:**

```
router.get('/tools', function(req, res){

})
```